# Boot from a windows bootable media without loading a driver

Tags: drivers, windows-installation

I have an HP dv6 notebook with an Intel integrated GPU and a discrete AMD GPU. This notebook series is known for having a problem with the AMD GPU, and mine is no exception. Every time it loads the GPU driver, the screen goes black, and the computer crashes.

I can use it by disabling the AMD GPU and using only the Intel one on my Windows installation (i.e., I uninstalled the AMD driver).
I tried to, but I cannot fully disable the AMD GPU from the BIOS, maybe with a custom BIOS, but I only found a very raw project of someone trying to do it.

So, the problem: I'm trying to do a fresh Windows install. When it boots from the USB drive, I suppose that it loads the AMD GPU driver, and then the installation crashes before starting.

Is there a way to remove the AMD GPU drivers from the installation media? Or do a 'security' boot with no drivers enabled?

Comment: I have owned a dv6T for years without any gpu issue ever.

Comment: At what point does it crash. If it’s after the installation, and it’s only crashing into the initial boot, use safe mode to avoid the driver being loaded and uninstall the driver. You will want to block the display driver using Microsoft’s tool

Comment: @Ramhound it crashes right after booting into the installation media, before the splash screen with the Windows logo.  How can I use safe mode booting from a flash drive?

Comment: @Moab well, maybe I'm unlucky, but I was able to find a lot of people on google with the same problem. The example I said on my original post: https://www.win-raid.com/t4199f16-HP-Pavilion-dv-c-ed-disable-remove-AMD-gpu-insyde-bios.html